# Turning For Loop into While loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I am attempting to turn this specific for-loop into a while-loop for experimental purposes, but I cannot seem to get the same result when I try to. Here are the loops that I have:

```c
int x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i += 8) {
  for (j = 0; j < M; j += 8) {
    for (k = i; k < i + 8; k++) {
      for (l = j; l < j + 8; l += 8) {
         x = l + k + i + j;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the while loop I've generated:

```c
int x = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k;
int l;
while (i < N) {
  while (j < M) {
    while (k < i + 8) {
      while (l < j + 8) {
        x = l + k + i + j;
        l += 8
        }
    k++
    l=j
    }
  j+=8
  k=i
  }
i+=8
}
```

Why wont the output be the same? What is wrong with the while loop set up that causes the difference with the for-loop?

Comment: 1. what are the type of i,j,k,l in your for loop? int?, 2. are you using any of the loop variables in your Some Code section?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan integers, and I am but only l and k. I am trying to see how I can increment correctly to match the behavior of the for loop incrementing

Comment: are you using any of the loop variables in your Some Code section?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan yes I am

Comment: Please describe what do you mean by `Why wont the output be the same`? whats the output you are getting in both cases and whats the expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please put brackets `{}` in appropriate positions. And you are incrementing `i` instead of `l` in inner most while loop. change,

```
    ...Some Code...
    i += 8
```

to

```
    ...Some Code...
    l += 8
```

Update:

In while loop you are assigning variables after executing the statement when for the for loop the initialisation happens before execution of the statement. Please assign each variable before execution and also check if conditions still satisfy.

Comment: Im sorry, that should be l, but what happens if it is still not producing the same result?

Comment: Please try to follow the answer and let me know if its still not working.

Comment: Why dont you initialize `k`, `l` with `0` before starting the loop?

Comment: Could you please show full code for `Some Code` section as you are using loop variables inside. You might be modifying them. need to check again.